# HTML Form won't connect with PHP (file access not allowed permission)

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm writing a form in HTML and after trying to call a PHP file to store the data, my apache server running on XAMPP displays the error

```
 failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage.php on line 5
```

Storage.php is my PHP file and is trying to write inputs from my HTML file into the txt doc wordfolder.txt.

I have changed all file permissions to read & write and I have gone into the command line and tried pretty much everything I can find

```
chmod 644 Desktop/wordfolder/wordfolder.txt,   
chmod -R 755 Desktop/wordfolder/wordfolder.txt,  
sudo chown -R Desktop/wordfolder/wordfolder.txt, 
chmod o+x Desktop/wordfolder/wordfolder.txt
```

My HTML file begins with

```
<form action="http://localhost/storage.php" method="get" onsubmit="window.location.reload()">
```

Comment: Make sure your txt file is closed.

Comment: Is closed, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: your forgot to add `/` at the end of your `$wordfolder` variable

Comment: Realized that, already changed.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments below, the problem turned out to be that the `x` bit wasn't set on the parent directories of the location the file was stored for the user attempting to write the file. The solution is to create a new folder, outside your home directory (e.g. `/Users/web`), chown it to the user that runs the web server and then it should be writable.

Comment: Try changing the line that says `file_put_contents("$wordfolder.wordfolder.txt", $wordinput, FILE_APPEND);}` to `file_put_contents($wordfolder."wordfolder.txt", $wordinput, FILE_APPEND);}`

Comment: Changed that in the code (thanks for the tip you were correct) but It still is saying access denied

Comment: Okay. I think the problem is that the file you are trying to write to is in a directory that can't itself be listed. To list a directory you need the `x` bit set on it. Personally, I would just move the file somewhere else, but if you really want to write the file in place you will probably need to `chmod o+x` all parent directories of the file you want to write.

Comment: Ok very possible, where would you suggest I move it? just a different directory, say documents?

Comment: I'd move it somewhere outside your home directory. You could make a `/Users/web` folder and chown that to the web server user, or `chmod 666`.

Comment: thank you so much! Finally got it to allow permission, now I have to figure out how to get the page to refresh (it wrote on my text document but didn't refresh form)

Comment: No problem. I'll update the answer in case anyone else has a similar problem in future.

Answer (score -1):

Try it;

```
chmod('file path', 0755);
```

Comment: chmod(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storage.php

Comment: file_put_contents("e:/1.txt", "contect", FILE_APPEND); no problem